# apply select_dtypes on dataframe colums

Tags: python

I have 2 dataframes. one of them is Train and the other one is Test. I made a list of these two dataframes to make data cleaning easier. now I want to encode the columns that have object type. the problem is that with this code I can select columns with object type but it won't be applied on the final data:

```
fulldata=[train,test]
for dataset in fulldata:
    dataset.select_dtypes(include='object').apply(le.fit_transform)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign to the relevant columns:

```py
fulldata=[train,test]
for dataset in fulldata:
    object_cols = dataset.select_dtypes(include='object').columns
    dataset_transf = dataset[object_cols].apply(le.fit_transform)
    dataset[object_cols] = dataset_transf
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. Could you please let me know what was my problem?

Comment: you need to assign the results back to the dataframe (`dataset[object_cols] =...`). Without that, you just perform the apply and dump the results.